# Map sequence of integers into repeating sequence

Tags: java

I have a continuous, ordered sequence of integers that start less than zero and go above zero; for instance `...,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`. I need to map these into a repeating sequence `3,6,9,12`, with the initial condition that `f(0)=3`. So for instance `f(-2)=9, f(-1)=12, f(0)=3, f(1)=6, f(2)=9, f(3)=12, f(4)=3` and so on. Is there a compact way to express this operation in Java, so that we are able to just use the remainder (%) operator and avoid any if/else statements?

Comment: sounds like homework to me. is it?

Comment: Sean - No, just something I have to do in an application involving date math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following to handle negative numbers.

```
public int f(int n, int ... sequence) {
  int idx = n % sequence.length;
  if (idx < 0) idx += sequence.length;  
  return sequence[idx];
}


int x = f(n, 3,6,9,12);
```

however in this specific example there is a much simpler solution ;)

```
public int f(int n) {
    return (n & 3) * 3 + 3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like very simple solution at the end, and it works for both positive and negative numbers.

Comment: I suspect the three 3's is the sort of solution expected.

Answer (score 2):

This would server your purpose:

```
    int repeatInt =  12 - ((11 - seqInt)*3) % 12 ;

where repeatInt = 3,9,6 or 12, the output 
  and seqInt = a number from your sequence
```

( forgive me for any syntax mistakes, I tried the code in PHP, and changed it to Java )

Comment: DhruvPathak - On closer inspection, this function doesn't work when seqInt >= 12. It then yields a repeating sequence 12, 15, 18, 21.

Answer (score 1):

```
int repeatingSequence[] = { 3,6,9,12 };
int fZero = 0;
int len = repeatingSequence.length;

public int f(int n) {
  return repeatingSequence[ (n % len + fZero + len) % len ];
}
```

Works for positives, negatives, and every fZero as the initial mapping condition.

Comment: Can you give an example of when fZero couldn't be 0? If it is 0, couldn't the expression be shorter?

Comment: @Peter, the initial condition of the mapping is arbitrary. `fZero=0;` is the case in the OP's question, which maps `{ 0->3, 1->6, 2->9, 3->12, 4->3, ... }`, `fZero=1;` produces an offset of 1, so the mapping looks like this `{ 0->6, 1->9, 2->12, 3->3, 4->6, ... }`

Comment: @Abiel, you're right, Java's modulus operator works strangely with negatives, see the updated version... I'll add an explanation momentarily

Comment: @davin, so you would agree that for any case where fZero != 0, you can replace it with fZero = 0 and simplify the code. ;)

Comment: @Peter, of course I would agree, although that would be loss of generality, if fZero has a valid range over all the naturals then you can't get around the second use of %

Comment: @davin, I would agree, except there is not a situation when you cannot change the order so that fZero is 0.

Comment: @Peter, but the question was that there is a given sequence, and an initial condition. My solution works under those constraints and doesn't request from the user to do extra work